# How to find a file containing CPU temperature and fan speed information in all Linux distros at same location?

Tags: c++, file, ubuntu, interface, health-monitoring

I am working on a project where I have to get CPU temperature (including cores) and fans speed.

For my PC, I have used `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon2/temp*_input` for the CPU and `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/device/fan*_input` for the fans speed.

My code does not works on some other PCs. First, the OS is Ubuntu 18.04 and the second is 16.04. I would like to find an universal path from where I can get all the necessary information. Is there anything like it that I can use?

Comment: No such luck. There are various temperature reading drivers/modules and no standardized way in which they report their results. Hwmon is probably as close as you'll get to a "standard".

Comment: ok.But Hwmon folder content is not the same in every pc.How can I universaly read it content?

Comment: AFAIK there is no universal way. Sucks, but that's life for you. You just have to probe different options, see what works on the current system and deal with it.

Comment: OK.Thanks.It was helpfull.

Comment: I don't think this is a bad question (or certainly not worthy of -2) given you provided the filesystem keys and testing results. Try [`lm-sensors` package](https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors). It should provide a cross-platform way to read some measurements on Linux 2.6.5 and later. You will need to use different libraries on BSDs, OS X, Solaris and other operating systems.

Comment: @jww thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be read from /sysfs interface, both from /sys/clsss/thermal or /sys/class/hwmon.

go through below link for more detail:

https://www.lookup2learn.com/post/thermal-management-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

**No, there is no such thing.**

The different measurements you want to read are scattered on the system, depending on drivers/modules or even Linux flavors.

You would have to find which readings you want to get, where you can get them or through specific tools.

`/sys/class/hwmon/` is the closest you can get.

You can find some documentation [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/sysfs-interface) for `hwmon` if you want to see what is supported.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no universal way. Sucks, but that's life for you. You just have to probe different options, see what works on the current system and deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I have tried to write a code that finds all the files with names temp*_input and fan*_input. After finding this files I have read the data stored on this files. This code works perfectly on all linux machines which has hwmon interface installed before.

Comment: I can not past any code now. The principe that I have explained works perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

This command will show current temparature:

```
cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone*/temp
```

Temperature monitoring and fan control is implemented using a standard kernel interface called `hwmon`. You can configure `sysfs` and `lm_sensors` interfaces to show fan speed and temperature. Check following guide for more detail answer:

https://github.com/Mellanox/mlxsw/wiki/Temperature-and-Fan-Control